# Plotting percentages from a csv file into matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe called orbital returns which I pulled from a csv:

```
orbitalreturns = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Orbital returns.csv',index_col=0,header=0) 

2014-02-28       NaN
2014-03-31     1.17%
2014-04-30     1.01%
2014-05-31     2.77%
2014-06-30     2.41%
2014-07-31    -5.44%
```

I simply want to plot it but get:

```
 TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

I have tried:

```
 orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'].strip('%')
```

but get:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: try: orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'].str.strip('%')

Comment: this worked great thanks - what about for $ (I switched the % w/ $)?  but get ValueError: could not convert string to float: $129.99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the % sign and convert to a floating point number:

```
 orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'] = orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns']\
                                        .str.strip('%').astype(float)
```

Comment: I was afraid this would fail with the `NaN` value, but it seems it doesn't, do you know why? Since `np.nan` has no `.strip()`.

Comment: Exactly because `np.nan` has no `.strip()`. In this case the function cannot be applied and the result _becomes_ `np.nan`. In a sense, the NaN that you have in the result is not the same NaN that you had in the original frame.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, I thought this was trying to `.strip` but leaving behind the same value if it couldn't work, but that's not the case then. Much appreciated and very good answer!

Answer (score 1):

To work with strings you need to use .str method as described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str

This code should work (errors will result in NaN-values - thanks for comment):

```
orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'] = pd.to_numeric(orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'].str.strip('%'),errors='coerce')
```

When printing:

```
orbitalreturns["OrbitalReturns"]
```

You get (which looks perfectly fine):

```
0    1.17
1    1.01
2    2.77
3    2.41
4   -5.44
Name: OrbitalReturns, dtype: float64
```

---

**Inspect the values in each serie below**:

```
orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'].values
# array([nan, '1.17%', '1.01%', '2.77%', '2.41%', '-5.44%'], dtype=object)

orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'].str.strip("%").values
# array([nan, '1.17', '1.01', '2.77', '2.41', '-5.44'], dtype=object)

pd.to_numeric(orbitalreturns['OrbitalReturns'].str.strip("%")).values
# array([  nan,  1.17,  1.01,  2.77,  2.41, -5.44])
```

Comment: IMO `pd.to_numeric()` is the most idiomatic way to convert to numbers. I would also add `errors='coerce'` parameter... +1

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for pointing that out, errors='coerce' is indeed the way to go when converting